# Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API Authentication from the frontend via API key possible?

Tags: api, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

The use case is a frontend application that does not have any backend so normally I would expect to use an api key ( https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys ) but in the complete text to speech documentation ( https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ ) I can't find any information about if (and how) its possible to use api keys for the Cloud Text-to-Speech API.

I don't think its such an uncommon use case to use the text to speech functionality in a standalone frontend (especially with the new WaveNet voices), so I thought I would ask the question here if anyone has some tips where to look for this information or if it's currently really only ment as an API usable in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same problem that I am facing right now then I can help you. I have the same issue asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773528/google-cloud-text-to-speech-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-403).

If you are using webpage to translate then you have to send your API key in URL of the request. The one way I tried is,

`https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?fields=audioContent&key={Your key goes here}`.

I hope this will solve your problem.