# Google cloud text-to-speech : the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to build a web page which will translate the text into mp3 using google cloud text-to-speech. After lots of search I found using REST API I can request the API to translate the text into mp3.

I am using JQuery and AJAX for the HTTP request.

Problem is that I am requesting the cloud server to translate the text using following data,

```
"data" : {
                   "input": {
                       "text": encodeURIComponent(text)
                    },

                    "voice" : {
                        "languageCode" : "en-US",
                        "name"         : "en-US-Wavenet-A",
                    },

                    "audioConfig" : {
                        "audioEncoding" : "MP3",
                    }
               },
```

By sending this I'm getting `error 403` which clearly says that I do not have access to perform the requested action, in [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#403_Forbidden) document

I know without API key and authorization I cannot access the service. So my questions is how can I send my API key and authorizations keys so that I can get the authorization and perform the requested action.

**Edit-1**

I am sending request to server using following URL,

```
https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?further_parameters_goes_here
```

If anyone want more information I can give it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Vaibhav M

Answer (score 4):

First you need to get your Google Cloud's API Key from your acount (https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) and try the code bellow, replacing **your-api-key** in the script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // An element to play the speech from Google Cloud
    var Sound = (function () {

        var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

        return function Sound(src) {

            var snd = new Audio(src);
            df.appendChild(snd); // keep in fragment until finished playing
            snd.addEventListener('ended', function () {df.removeChild(snd);});
            snd.play();
            return snd;
        }

    }());

    // The settings for the Ajax Request
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1/text:synthesize",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "x-goog-api-key": "**your-api-key**",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": "{'input':{'text':'I have added the event to your calendar.'},'voice':{'languageCode':'en-gb','name':'en-GB-Standard-A','ssmlGender':'FEMALE'},'audioConfig':{'audioEncoding':'MP3' }}"
    }

    // The Ajax Request, on success play the speech
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response.audioContent);
      var snd = Sound("data:audio/wav;base64," + response.audioContent);
    });

});
```

Comment: Any idea why using this code leads to response of error code 500 (internal server error) for about 1 in every 5 calls?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your API key as a header, the header field is "X-Goog-Api-Key". Also make sure you're setting the proper body encoding in the request using the "Content-Type" header, in your case I think it should be "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8". And lastly, I'm think you shouldn't be encoding the text field in the request body.

If you don't have the API key yet, you can follow these steps to get to it

1. Create a project (or use an existing one) in the [Cloud
   Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. Make sure that [billing](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=_) is enabled for your project.
3. Enable the [Text-to-Speech API](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=texttospeech.googleapis.com).
4. Create an [API key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_).

I'm not familiar with JQuery and AJAX syntax, but you could use this curl command for reference

```
Curl -H "X-Goog-Api-Key: PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input':{
      'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google,
         based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for
         touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-gb',
      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize" > synthesize-text.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. First of all I didn't found any such header field in docs of google cloud you told i.e  "X-Goog-Api-Key". Does it is used in curl? Second the format you given from `-H "Content-Type: ` to `'audioEncoding':'MP3'` is same as that I am using. And the third I'm encoding the text using encodeURIComponent. Also I have the API key but the problem is that I don't know how to use it in HTTP request that I'm sending. If you want any code I can post it.

Comment: @VaibhavMandlik The "X-Goog-Api-Key" HTTP **header** can be used with any Google Cloud API, see docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters). Again, don't encode the text within the request data, you'll get unexpected results. The curl command above was just a quick way to demonstrate how to make the API request with the proper format, you can test it out in Terminal, and then based on it create your request with JQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try it for sure as you are telling.

Answer (score 1):

I found out two possibilities that can help you.

1. Obtain a Bearer token.

If you installed the Cloud SDK, you can easily get the token with this command: [gcloud auth application-default print-access-token](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization). It can be executed in the Cloud Shell too. Just be sure that the default user you are logged in has the appropriate role to access the text-to-speech service. Then, attach the token to the header request, for example a final request can look like this.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.GqUB8gVkiMCyl2ZCKEfS8Tb9QmS_LRb1bQP__fIPYbCU.....LUAlCRJU9OpFc_hCzSVUwlAZAhac2aZhoh" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input: {
      'text': 'my custom text'
    },
    'voice' : {
      'languageCode' : 'en-US',
      'name'           : 'en-US-Wavenet-A'
    },
    'audioConfig' : {
      'audioEncoding' : 'MP3'
    }
}" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize"
```

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol#synthesize_audio_from_text) integrates the request and the command in one step.

2. Obtain an API key.

An API key is more portable than a token, but it can be used by anyone who possess it. It's recommended to [restrict such key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions) to the text-to-speech service. Then, you should use [the key in the endpoint URL](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#using_an_api_key), for example "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=AIzaSynAJU-EGnhdDaaXH4NVcc". A complete example looks like the following:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data "{
    'input':{
      'text':'my custom text'
    },
    'voice':{
      'languageCode':'en-gb',
      'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
      'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
    },
    'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
    }
  }" "https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=AIzaSynAJU-EGnhdDaaXH4NVcc"
```